# creating two tables in android app database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create two tables in my android app database and the application crashes when i'm tring to insert values to the first table, but when i delete the database and recreate it only with one table, it works fine. i don't get it?

the code is:

```
private static String query_create_user = "CREATE TABLE User ( email TEXT PRIMARY KEY, firstName TEXT,  lastName TEXT, password TEXT)";
private static String query_create_group = "CREATE TABLE Group ( groupNumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, courseNumber INTEGER, groupName TEXT, groupType TEXT, groupOwner TEXT)";

public SchoolBagDataBase (Context applicationcontext) {

    super(applicationcontext, "contract.db", null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

   database.execSQL(query_create_user);
   database.execSQL(query_create_group);

}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post your LogCat? And also, your code to insert the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL statement held in string 'query_create_group' is invalid. You can't have a table called Group because GROUP is a reserved word in SQLite. Just choose a different name for your table.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept the answer that solves your problem. I'm not just fishing for rep here, you get some too and it helps others who see this page more easily see what the solution was.